# What are some online compilers to compile and run PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, saas

I want to execute programs of PL/SQL on-line for practice.
Can any one suggest me any websites which will compile and run the code and show the result?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Below are some of the online websites that can help in executing Oracle SQL queries and PL/SQL Code -

- [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wh4zpMKJ) - Easily create schemas and queries and share them with others.
- [Oracle Live Sql](https://livesql.oracle.com/) - All your PL/SQL scripts can be saved. Requires a free Oracle account.
- [Oracle Apex](http://apex.oracle.com)  -Test out Apex, which also lets you create objects and run scripts. Requires a free Oracle account.
- [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/oracle_terminal_online.php)-
  create objects and run scripts

In coding ground you can execute .sql scripts by using below steps.

1.Click on new project.

2.Click on '+' symbol. `-- A new .sql file will be created (Newfile.sql)`

3.Execute the .sql as @**filename**.sql      (Ex : `@Newfile.sql` )

Answer (score 25):

**Update 2024-01-17:** SQL Fiddle no longer works for Oracle and seems to have lost many old fiddles. See the other answer for a more up-to-date list.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Here is a trivial example of use:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8cf15/5