# run oracle sql code online

Tags: sql, oracle, analyzer

Is there any website where you can write oracle sql code, maybe even build a small database to work on, run it and see an output? I've tried searching online but I couldn't really find anything besides [W3Schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all).

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with [tag:compiler-construction]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of January 2024, SQL Fiddle has been completely redesigned/rebuilt and **no longer supports Oracle**. Previous fiddles included in (many) questions and answers are no longer available.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685433/4266332) for alternatives.

I'll leave this answer here as a signpost for now.

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) will let you build schema objects and run queries against them. It's great for trying things out. It has become quite common for answers here to include a link to a Fiddle to demonstrate a code sample (including [quite a few of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a266304%20sql%20fiddle), apparently).

It's free, but welcomes donations.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about this one. I came across SQL Fiddle a while ago. It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: is sql fiddle working ? it is not working well.

Comment: No, it is not working well unfortunately. Still looking for a better alternative at the moment.